# Can't parse and return ajax string to jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, callback

`var data` is my jquery variable, i want to add `jsonData.image_name` string text in to it. but keep saying `undefined` when it passes.

```
function SaveAndGetImageName() {
    var data = "";
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('btn_Browse', $('#btn_Browse')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '../Gem/SaveProfilePic',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (jsonData) {
            data = jsonData.image_name;
        }
    });

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Why did you set `contentType` to false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cant return data from Asynchronous calls, you should do the manipulation in the success callback function. As callbacks are called when the data is arrived, but you are returning the data before that so you are getting `undefined`.

```
function SaveAndGetImageName(processImageNameCallback) {
    var data = "";
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('btn_Browse', $('#btn_Browse')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '../Gem/SaveProfilePic',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (jsonData) {
            data = jsonData.image_name;
            processImageNameCallback(data);
        }
    });

    return data;
}

function processImageName(imageName){
   // do stuff with image name
   alert(imageName);
}

SaveAndGetImageName(processImageName)
```

Comment: Thax u so much mate, it worked.